# Unable to locate element using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I have been trying to find a button a click on it but no matter what I try it has been unable to locate it. I have tried using all the `driver.find_element_by...` methods but nothing seems to be working

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/shreygupta/Documents/ComputerScience/PythonLanguage/Automation/corona/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-track-note='chart-click-data']").click()
```

I am trying to click the DATA tab on the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your script to open this graph directly:

```py
driver.get("https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/total-cases-covid-19")
driver.maximize_window()
```

Then you can add `implicitly_wait` instead of `sleep`. An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available ([from python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)). It'll work way faster because it'll interact with an element as soon as it finds it.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-track-note='chart-click-data']").click()
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic that you can use, where the script will wait for max 30 for the `Data` menu item and if the element is present with in 30 seconds it will click on the element.

```
url = "https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/covid-confirmed-cases-since-100th-case"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[data-track-note='chart-click-data']"))).click()
```